# iOS Line charts with multiple y-axis

Tags: iphone, graph, core-plot

I am able to displaying multiple Y-axis using core plot, but my problem is I need to display different values on two Y-axis with different interval difference.

[image]

[image]

How to draw graphs using core plot same as above images.

Is it possible to draw graphs or not. If not possible please tell me reason.

If possible give me some suggestion or provide sample code using core plot.

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a separate "plot space" for each different axis scale. For these graphs, you would need two—one for the left y-axis and the x-axis and another for the right y-axis. See the Plot Gallery (the Plot Space demo) and CPTTestApp (Mac version) example apps for sample code.

Answer (score 0):

For LineChartDataSet you have property axisDependency. This property could be

```
AxisDependencyLeft
AxisDependencyRight
```

For swift

```
.Left
.Right
```